# Proving that for all positive integers, the partitions $p(n) < p(n+1)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

Prove that the number of partitions of a number $n$ is less than the number of partitions of $n+1$. Now this seems quite trivial, but oddly enough, I'm not even sure how to go about proving it (ideally without generating functions since the question does not assume knowledge of them yet)?

Initially I thought of doing something along the lines of

$$ p(n+1) - p(n) > 0$$

and then proving by induction with base cases 1 and 2, however, I can't seem to not run in to generating functions for this...

Does anyone have any other insight on how to go about proving them? Ferrer's diagrams potentially?

Comment: Can you see any way to get a 1-1 map from partitions of $n$ to those of $n+1$?  This would show $p(n) \leq p(n+1)$.  To get strict inequality, can you find a partition of $n+1$ not already mapped to?

Comment: So if we add one dot on the Ferrer's diagram to each partition of n we get a partition of n+1. However, there's always the partition that takes one dot in every row which we can't map to? Is this correct? I just drew it out for 1,2 and 3,4

Comment: It looks reasonable You might want to try writing it out in detail as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Does it suffice to show a 1-1 mapping of p(n) to p(n+1) and then show one partition that it does not map to?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_n$ denote the set of all partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\}.$ Define a map $$f:P_n\to P_{n+1},\hspace{1cm} f(p_1,\ldots,p_k):=(1,p_1,\ldots,p_k)$$

Then $f$ is clearly injective, so $p(n)\leq p(n+1)$. However, $f$ is certainly not surjective since the trivial partition $(n+1)$ is not in the image of $f$. Therefore $p(n)<p(n+1)$.